# Why does select IF(null <> 1,"true","false") return false? null is not 1?

Tags: mysql

Why does select `IF(null <> 1,"true","false")` return false?  null is not 1?!

Comment: Null is not anything, it is null. That is why you must use `IS NULL` and not comparison operators

Comment: Try `SELECT NULL <> 1`. The result is `NULL`, not true or false.

Comment: NULL is "unknown". Does 1 is not equal to some unknown value? maybe yes, maybe no, i.e. unknown. So NULL<>1 is NULL which is treated as false in binary logic.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` cannot be tested with `=` or `<>`.  By definition, such tests *always* fail.

Instead, to test a column `col` for nullness, use one of these, as appropriate:

```
col IS NULL
col IS NOT NULL
```

There is also `<=>`, but read the manual on the details.  It may be 'correct' to change to this (but I am not sure):

```
IF(null <=> 1, "false", "true")
```

If the "null" is coming from app code, then consider one of these (or many other possibilities) to turn `NULL` into something that can be compared:

```
IFNULL(?, 0)
COALESCE(?, 0)
```

Another thing to consider

```
IF(<<some test>>, true, false)
```

can be replaced by simply the test.

But if you really need the *strings* `"true"` and `"false"`, then this tip does not apply.

These understand NULL:  <=>, IFNULL(), COALESE(), IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, COUNT(col) (by not counting the row when col IS NULL), LEFT JOIN (by generating NULLs), etc

These do not understand NULL, and simply return NULL: +, -, *, /, <, >, etc.

Comment: In other words, "NULL is just not..."